# Is there a way to download file(output by ci job) from browser in gitlab ci?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I can run script for build my project in `gitlab-ci.yaml` config.Is there a way let pipline download the file output by build script from browser, then i can find it in my computer?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [job artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) from the output of commands from your pipeline (like your build script), assuming you have redirected said output in a file.

You can then download job artifacts by using the GitLab UI or the [API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html#get-job-artifacts).
Using the [GitLab CLI glab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/glab):

```
glab ci artifact <refName> <jobName> [flags]

# example
glab ci artifact main build
```

Comment: @eder Great! Can you post the gitlab-ci script you ended up using here? That will help others.

Comment: sure.I post it on the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is my ci config, to download build-files on Gitlab UI via `artifact` field.

```yaml
stages:
    - build

.build-base:
    stage: build
    script:
        - cd dev/${APP_PATH}
        - yarn ${BUILD_SCRIPT}
    when: manual
    after_script:
        - mv dev/${APP_PATH}/dist ./${APP_OUTPUT_NAME}
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - ./${APP_OUTPUT_NAME}
        expire_in: 2 week
        name: ${APP_OUTPUT_NAME}_${CI_JOB_ID}
    tags:
        - kube-runner

order_workbench_sit_build:
    extends: .build-base
    variables:
        APP_PATH: 'order-management'
        BUILD_SCRIPT: 'build:sit'
        APP_OUTPUT_NAME: 'order_workbench_sit'

order_workbench_build:
    extends: .build-base
    variables:
        APP_PATH: 'order-management'
        BUILD_SCRIPT: 'build'
        APP_OUTPUT_NAME: 'order_workbench'
```

Comment: Great feedback. Good use of the after_script.